# jQuery - How to get Print Screen image

Tags: javascript, jquery, screenshot

I am trying to make a jQuery code to save a screenshot in my web page. I found a lot of plugins that take screenshot of pages.
But this is what I want:

1- The user takes a Print Screen of a issue in the desktop(not in the browser)
 2- The user clicks on a Button 'save' in my web page
 3- jQuery gets that image and saves into a folder

All the ways I found was to take a WebPage Screenshot.
Is there a way to get the Image that the user toke?

Comment: You can upload files using HTML5 forms.

Comment: But at the job, some users have IE 8

Comment: You can have the user paste the image into a web page, an answer exists for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15960492/paste-image-to-a-web-page I think you're going to have a difficult time to support IE8... in which case I suggest perhaps degrading gracefully, where modern browsers can paste and older browsers have to use a file upload mechanism.

Comment: Oops, it's supported way before HTML5. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Ok thanks, gona try...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it may help you,http://codepen.io/reynard2007/pen/xfwoK , i remember long a go i see one codepen is doing the function you want,that is pasting the image in to a `canvas`